# Keras - UpSampling2D layer appears to be returning a 2D tensor rather than 4D

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am feeding 1080x1616 color photos into a convolutional neural network in Keras. The data is fed through the network just fine, until it gets to the last convolutional layer, throwing an error saying that it expects a 4D tensor, but instead gets a (32,1) tensor. I don't understand where this number is being generated.

This is my model architecture:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
        Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', data_format="channels_last", input_shape=(self.x_res,self.y_res,self.n_channels), kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal()),
        MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
        Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal()),
        MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal()),
        MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal()),
        UpSampling2D((2, 2)),
        Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal()),
        UpSampling2D((2, 2)),   
        Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal()),
        UpSampling2D((2, 2)),
        Conv2D(self.n_channels, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal())
    ])
```

And this is from model.summary()

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 1080, 1616, 32)    896
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 540, 808, 32)      0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 540, 808, 64)      18496
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 270, 404, 64)      0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 270, 404, 128)     73856
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 135, 202, 128)     0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 135, 202, 256)     295168
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2 (None, 270, 404, 256)     0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 270, 404, 128)     295040
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2 (None, 540, 808, 128)     0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 540, 808, 64)      73792
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_3 (UpSampling2 (None, 1080, 1616, 64)    0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 1080, 1616, 3)     195
=================================================================
Total params: 757,443
Trainable params: 757,443
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

The Keras documentation for the UpSampling2D layer says:

```
Output shape

4D tensor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input to your model should be of shape (batch_size, x_res, y_res, n_channels), please check it.

Following is a simple test:

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
import numpy as np

x_res = 1080
y_res = 1616
n_channels = 3

model = keras.Sequential([
        Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', data_format="channels_last", input_shape=(x_res,y_res,n_channels), kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal()),
        MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
        Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal()),
        MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal()),
        MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal()),
        UpSampling2D((2, 2)),
        Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal()),
        UpSampling2D((2, 2)),   
        Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal()),
        UpSampling2D((2, 2)),
        Conv2D(n_channels, (1, 1), padding='same', activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal())
    ])

image = np.random.randn(1, x_res, y_res, n_channels)

model.predict(image)
```

Comment: Yes, this is a perfect answer, didn't think that was the issue considering the error wasn't thrown until the last layer. So, all I have to do is reshape my training data so it has the batch size as the first element. Thank you!